# Dynamically Insert into table while checking if the record already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I had some doubts on dynamic insertion of data while doing an insert statement so just wanted to get some assistance from you guys.  I have to do multiple insert statements say around 1500 records based on 2 different criteria's below is just a sample of 1 insert statement.
Now while doing an insert statement I want to dynamically assign the USERID's and ROLEid's the 2 columns which you can see in the query below. 
So for example where userid IN (500 different userid) and role id in (100 different) ones.

```
Insert into userrolelist (Userid, Roleid, IsDefault, EffectiveStart, 
EffectiveEnd, Clientid, LastmodifiedUserId, LastmodifiedTimestamp)
Values (161514,1011,1,'2016-01-21 00:00:00.001',Null,16785,0,'2016-01-21 
00:00:00.001')
```

I am sure there is a way to do dynamic insertion based on 2 different criteria's I am just confused as to how can I achieve that. Mainly also because for each criteria before insertion I need to check if that userid + roleid combination already exists in the table. Because if I dont check it and still do an insert it will throw an error because there is a constraint based on the 2 fields.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated. Please let me know if the question is not very clear and i can add a bit more explanation if required. Thank you.

Comment: You can probably do multiple inserts with a single select statement which also checks whether or not the userid/roleid combination you're trying to insert already exists in the table. But it's hard to be any more specific than that without something like sample data (more than the single row you've provided).

Comment: @ZLK - I can try to get a screenshot of sample data for you. Can you give me some idea about how to check the already exists in the select statement with multiple conditions ? like a userid +role id

Comment: Well let's say I'm inserting things into a table based on another table. I might do something like `INSERT INTO myTable (column1, column2...) SELECT column1, column2... FROM myOtherTable AS O WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE column1 = O.column1 AND column2 = O.column2);` or something like that. I can add other where conditions to the select statement if necessary and also change what I insert with case statements if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say where your lists of user IDs and role IDs are coming from, but because you specify different numbers for each of them, I assume that they are separate lists, rather than a single list of pairs.  And I assume that they are stored in tables named `userlist` and `rolelist`, respectively.  Then you can do the insert as follows:

```
insert into userrolelist
    (Userid, Roleid, IsDefault, EffectiveStart, EffectiveEnd, 
    Clientid, LastmodifiedUserId, LastmodifiedTimestamp)
select
    userid, roleid,
    1,'2016-01-21 00:00:00.001',Null,16785,0,
    '2016-01-21 00:00:00.001'
from
    (select userid, roleid 
    from userlist
        cross join rolelist
    ) as userrole
where
    not exists (select 1 from userrolelist as ur where ur.userid=userrole.userid and ur.roleid=userrole.roleid);
```

The subquery constructs a list of all possible pairs of users and roles, so if you already have a list of pairs, you can simply use that in place of the subquery.